# iOS swift like Post like Instagram or Facebook Like

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in my app I have a timeline( `tableView` with custom `cell` ) like Instagram or Facebook app, and user can like post (heart button like Instagram that have 2 sate, white or red).
I want to when taped like button by user, change like/unlike as offline and when user reload a data with new value from server with update it automatically set it.

I appreciate if you guys tell me what is instruction for do that.
thanks

Comment: just create a custom tableviewcell

Comment: @Vyacheslav I do that, I mean what I do when like button touch

Comment: Handle tap vutton action for your button

Comment: Write your base code for ui tablecell.

Answer (score 0):

In your cell on your button action

```
// button action
func didPressLikeButton(_ button: UIButton) {

    //check current value
    if (button.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "like")) {
        //set default
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "default"), for: .normal)
    } else{
        // set like
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dear @Andrew Veresov but I have a new issue, I record video to show that issue: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8744173/quickcast-23-07-1395-01-02-13.mp4, when I click The like button in index of 0, the like button in index of 3 change state also.

Comment: @MohammadReze It seems the table reusing it. You should check: post liked or not in the table data source method cellForRowAtIndexPath if liked set like the image for button otherwise set default.

Comment: Not working when I put button in cell try it before